# Regular Expression to prevent Email Name Spoofing

Tags: regex

I want to match everything where `.com` or `my\s?example` appears in the display name of a **From** header ***and*** where the **From** email address is ***not*** `.*@myexample.com`.

It's easy when the display name is enclosed by quotation marks, but fails when the quotation marks are absent.

```
"(.*?(my\s?example|\.com).*?)"(?!\s?\<.*?\@myexample\.com\>)
```

Please see here:
https://regexr.com/5im6l

Everything works as desired except for the last line in the input field, where the double quotes are missing. I would like it to also match for this.

Comment: Something like `From:\s*(.*?(?:my\s?example|\.com).*?)\s+<(?!\s*<[^<>]*@myexample\.com>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an if clause is supported, and you want to capture what is between the double quotes if they are both there or capture the whole string if there are no double quotes at the start and end, you might use:

```
\bFrom:\s(")?(.*?\b(my\s?example|\.com)\b.*?)(?(1)")\s+<(?!\s?[^\r\n<>]*@myexample\.com>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bFrom:\s(")?` A word boundary, match `From:`  and optionally capture `"` in **group 1**
- `(.*?\b(my\s?example|\.com)\b.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match a part that contains either `myexample` or `.com` where the alternatives are in **group 3**
- `(?(1)")` If clause, if group 1 exists, match `"` so it is not part of the capture group
- `\s+<` Match 1+ whitespace chars and `<`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what is at the right is not

  - `\s?[^\r\n<>]*@myexample\.com>` Match `@myexample\.com` between the brackets
- `)` Close lookahead

Group 2 contains the whole match, and group 3 contains a part with either `Myexample` or `.com` using a case insensitive match.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5BvwcU/1)

---

If `\K` is supported to forget what is matched so far, and you want as another example a match only:

```
\bFrom:\s"?\K.*?\b(?:my\s?example|\.com)\b.*?(?="?\s<(?![^<>]*@myexample\.com>))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9BSYxM/1)

Note that you don't have to escape `\<` `\>` and `\@`